# WebBrowser in WebApi

Tags: c#, iis, webbrowser-control

1. Sorry for my bad English
2. Access a page that needs login, I use WebBrowser for this, running through IIS Express works (running in visual studio).
3. The problem is when I configure the application on an Amazon server, using IIS too, it simply loses the authentication that the site needs.
4. Example Code:

   ```
   using (WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser())
   {
       //authentication is here

   webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.example.com/user=admin/password=123123");

       //page that I need to access
       webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.example.com/downloads/doc.pdf");
   }
   ```

OBS: This code works by running visual studio, the problem is when I set up the Amazon server, it simply loses the authentication

Comment: `WebBrowser` is not designed for ASP.NET. Please use something like Chrome, as it supports headless mode, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome Something might work in Visual Studio, simply because IIS Express runs your web app as yourself and in your user session. However, once on IIS the web app no longer runs under your account, and it is also isolated in session 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer